# image randomizer in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a html page with a image randomizer using code I found somewhere. 
The code, however, compels me to set a width and a height in pixels.
so when I use the code on a div the image does not scale which is bad for the fluid layout I use.
(when I set width to auto or 100% in css the image simply doesn't show)
how do I alter the code so it works in a fluid layout?
here's my css:

```
.stretcher {
/*#bg {*/
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: -69;
width:1366px;
height:768px;
}
```

the head part of my html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var header = document.getElementById('bg');
    var pictures = new Array('bgs/1.jpg','bgs/2.jpg','bgs/3.jpg','bgs/4.jpg','bgs/5.jpg');
    var numPics = pictures.length;
    if (document.images) {
        var chosenPic = Math.floor((Math.random() * numPics));
        header.style.background = 'url(' + pictures[chosenPic] + ')';
    }
}
```

and the div in the body:

```
<div class="stretcher" id="bg"></div>
```

Comment: Does it neither work when the `position` has been set to `relative`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zwq0pasg/ use `background-size:cover`

Comment: I assume `#bg` is not the only element on the page. How did you style the parent elements?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can set `width` and `heigth` to 100% and then the image as background `cover`:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/yudumn2p/)

CSS:

```
.stretcher {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -69;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

JS:

```
function cycle() {
    var header = document.getElementById('bg');
    var pictures = new Array('http://advancement.georgetown.edu/advent/wallpapers/ui/img/1366x768/SealWP_1366x768.jpg', 'http://www.sonymobile.co.jp/xperia/docomo/so-01d/common/download/wallpaper/1366-768/xperiaplaywp_1366-768_bk02.jpg');
    var numPics = pictures.length;
    if (document.images) {
        var chosenPic = Math.floor((Math.random() * numPics));
        header.style.background = 'url(' + pictures[chosenPic] + ')';
        header.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
    }
}

cycle();
```

Answer (score 0):

use header.style.backgroundImage instead, so it won't override the css, 
from my comment.

```js
var header = document.getElementById('bg');
    var pictures = new Array('http://placekitten.com/g/200/300','http://placekitten.com/g/100/300','http://placekitten.com/g/500/300','http://placekitten.com/g/500/300','http://placekitten.com/g/200/700');
    var numPics = pictures.length;
    if (document.images) {
        var chosenPic = Math.floor((Math.random() * numPics));
        header.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + pictures[chosenPic] + ')';
    }
```

```css
.stretcher {
/*#bg {*/
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: -69;
width:100%;
height:768px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: middle middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.parent {
  width:500px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="stretcher" id="bg"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: the code does not scale the div completely, so when viewed on a smaller screen (tablet, phone) the image is shown only partly. I tried lots of things, like placing the div inside another div, fiddling with the css attributes, but I can't get it to work the way I want to. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If you want to show the entire img. Use contain instead of cover